# what is the difference between cpu cache and memory cache

Tags: java, caching, concurrency

What is the difference between cpu cache and memory cache?

> When data is cached in memory there is also a higher probability that
>   this data is also cached in the CPU cache of the CPU executing the
>   thread. [[1](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/concurrency-models.html)]

And how we can relate caching in cpu and memory?

Comment: CPU and Memory Cache are the same... Unless of course your referring to Registers and Cache. If that's the case... http://superuser.com/questions/208932/difference-between-cache-memory-and-register

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To go into detail your question relates to both hardware and software used in computing.

**Cache**

This is just a general term used to refer to sets of data that are accessed quite often.

> In computing, a cache /ˈkæʃ/ kash,[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)) is a hardware or software component that stores data so future requests for that data can be served faster.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing))

**Memory Cache**

Quite simply is a cache of frequently accessed data that is stored in a reasonably fast medium, e.g. in RAM or on a disk drive.

**CPU Cache**

This is a small block of RAM like memory that is physically a part of the CPU. It generally doesn't have alot of memory.

e.g. The Intel Core 17-920 has a cache of 8MB 
[Source](https://ark.intel.com/products/37147/Intel-Core-i7-920-Processor-8M-Cache-2_66-GHz-4_80-GTs-Intel-QPI)

The point of this cache is to store data that the CPU is using quite regularly to speed up transfer time, since the CPU cache is physically closer to the processor then RAM is.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing));

> In computing, a cache is a hardware or software component that stores
>   data so future requests for that data can be served faster

So basically it is a location where you store data so that the next time you want the data you can access it quicker.  Which means that the cache needs to be in a location which is quicker than the original location.

Typically the hard disk is used to store most data in a persistent manner.  This is the largest data store in a computer system and is normally slow.

All the "work" is however done by the CPU.  So in order to do processing of the data the CPU needs to first read the data, then process it, then write it out.  As the CPU has a very limited memory/data registers then it does a lot of reading and writing.

Ideally your CPU would have a large enough data registers to store everything you need.  But memory on the CPU is very expensive, so this is not practical.

So, you have main memory where the applications store some data temporarily while running to make it quicker.

The way that applications work mean that you tend to have a lot of data which is accessed very frequently.  Often referred to as hot data.

So the purpose of the cache is to store such hot data so that you can quicker and easier refer to it and use it when needed.

So the closer to the CPU core you have your data, the quicker it can be accessed and hence performance is increased.  But the more expensive it is.

The graphic shows this the different levels together with approx. access times
[image]

It can vary slightly depending on CPU architecture (and has changed over time) but generally a L1 & L2 cache is per core.  A L3 cache is shared between multiple cores.  A L1 cache is also often split into a Data cache and an instructions cache.

So your CPU cache will contain data is which accessed the most at that time, so there is a relation of sorts to either the main memory or the HDD where the data was fetched from.  But because it is small, the cache will quickly change to using other data if you do something else, or something else if running in the background.

It is therefore not really possible to control the cache of the CPU.  Plus if you did you would effectively slow down everything else (including the O/S) because you are denying them the ability to use the cache.

Every time your application reads and stores data in main memory then it is effectively creating its own cache, assuming you then access the data from this location and don't read it from disk (or other location) every time you need it.

So this can mean that part of it is also in the CPU Cache, but not necessarily.  As you can have data in your main memory from your application, but you application is not doing anything, or has not accessed that data for a long time.

Remember also that the data in the CPU caches are very small in comparison to data in main memory.  For example the [Broadwell Intel Xeon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadwell_(microarchitecture)) chips have;

- L1 Cache = 64 KB (per core)
- L2 Cache = 256 KB (per core)
- L3 Cache = 2   - 6 MB (shared).

Answer (score 0):

The "memory cache" appears to really just be talking about anywhere in memory.  Sometimes this is a cache of data stored on disk or externally. This is a software cache.

The CPU cache is a hardware cache and is faster, more localised but smaller.